# Storage pool on Synology NAS

Tags: nas, synology

I have 1 SA3400 with 12 x 16 TB and 1x RX1217Sas with 12x 16 TB . I have a few questions:

how to shut down the expansion? I shutting down the sa3400, but the expansion is not turned off

My plan is to create 2 volume, 12 x 16 from SA3400 and 12 x 16 TB from expansion. what is the best storage pool, it's better to create one pool with 24 disks for 2 volume ? or create 2 storage pool @12disk each for each volume? and what is the

Comment: What kind of RAD array do you consider to use?

Comment: RAID 6 @RomeoNinov

Answer (score 1):

Will be wise to create two pools and then manage the shares separately. The reason is even with RAID6 you should not create pools with so big so many disks. The problem is recovery time. With so many disks you have the probability to get fail of disk during recovery from previous fail. OK, RAID6 will survive but you can get next disk failed.

I personally will set (on 12 disks) RAID6 + spare disk to ensure the business continuity.